# Passport expiring soon

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, layovers, switzerland

My passport is expiring on July 4, 2018 and I'm traveling from Chicago to Delhi. Being an Indian citizen, can I stay for a 2-hour layover in Zurich, Switzerland, without getting into trouble, or should I cancel that ticket?

Comment: You haven't shared your date of travel, so it's anyone's guess whether you'd have a problem. Assuming you're travelling close to 4th July, I'd say you have ample time to renew your passport.

Comment: @NRandhawa, Amrish could be a long-term resident in the USA, and is returning home.